# ending text based game in Python

Tags: python

```
# Written by: Jackie Burns
# Date: 2/25/2024

def show_intro(player_name=None):
    # Print intro
    print('\nWelcome to Lost in the Enchanted Forest,', player_name + '!', '\n', '------------------------------', '\n',
          '*** STORYLINE ***', '\n',
          'You, the brave adventurer, find yourself lost in the heart of the Enchanted Forest. ', '\n',
          'The forest is shrouded in mystery, with ancient trees, magical creatures, and hidden ', '\n',
          'secrets. Your mission is to collect six mystical artifacts scattered throughout the ', '\n',
          'forest before encountering the formidable villain, the Shadow Sorcerer. Legend has it ', '\n',
          'that these artifacts hold the power to break the sorcerer’s curse and restore balance ', '\n',
          'to the realm!')


def show_instructions():
    """
    Print a main menu and the commands
    """

    print("***Brave Adventurer in the Enchanted Forest Text Adventure Game***\n")
    print("\nCollect 6 items to win the game, or be taken by the sorcerer’s curse.\n")
    print("\nMove commands: \ngo South, go North, go East, go West")
    print("\nTo collect mystical artifacts, add them to your Inventory:\n get 'item name'")


def player_status(current_room, items_collected, rooms):
    """
    Display the Player's current status

    Arguments:
        current_room: string
        items_collected: list
        rooms: dictionary
    """

    print(f'You are in the {current_room}')
    if 'item' in rooms[current_room]:
        print(f'There is an item in this room: {rooms[current_room]["item"]}')
    print(f'Inventory: {items_collected}')
    print("*************************")
    print("Enter your move:")


def allitems(items_collected):
    """
    Check whether all six mystical artifacts are collected or not

    Arguments:
        items_collected: list

    Returns:
        True/False: bool
    """
    i = ['Luminous Crystal', 'Moonflower Petal', "Goblin's Key", 'Ancient Rune Tablet', 'Spider Silk Rope',
         'Thornbane Potion']
    return set(items_collected) == set(i)  # Check if the sets are equal


def main():
    """
    Main function
    """
    # Your implementation for the game logic goes here
    # For example, handle user input, move between rooms, and collect artifacts
    # Remember to update the current room and inventory based on user actions
    # Use the functions provided above to display information to the player

    # Example usage:
    player_name = input("Enter your name: ")
    show_intro(player_name)

    # Initialize game variables (current_room, items_collected, etc.)
    current_room = 'Forest Clearing'
    items_collected = []
    
    rooms = {
        'Forest Clearing': {'North': 'Ancient Oak Grove'},  # Start
        'Ancient Oak Grove': {'North': 'Whispering Brook', 'East': 'Goblin Caves', 'item': 'Luminous Crystal'},
        'Whispering Brook': {'East': 'Mystic Glade', 'South': 'Ancient Oak Grove', 'item': 'Moonflower Petal'},
        'Goblin Caves': {'North': 'Spiderweb Chamber', 'West': 'Ancient Oak Grove', 'item': "Goblin's Key"},
        'Mystic Glade': {'East': 'Eerie Ruins', 'West': 'Whispering Brook', 'item': 'Ancient Rune Tablet'},
        'Spiderweb Chamber': {'North': 'Eerie Ruins', 'South': 'Goblin Caves', 'item': 'Spider Silk Rope'},
        'Eerie Ruins': {'North': 'Thorned Thicket', 'West': 'Mystic Glade', 'South': 'Spiderweb Chamber',
                        'item': 'Thornbane Potion'},
        'Thorned Thicket': {'South': 'Eerie Ruins'}  # villain
    }

    # Implement game loop and user interactions
    while True:
        player_status(current_room, items_collected, rooms)

        # Handle user input and update game state accordingly
        command = input().strip().lower()

        # Check if the player wants to move
        if command.startswith('go '):
            direction = command[3:].capitalize()
            if direction in rooms[current_room]:
                current_room = rooms[current_room][direction]
            else:
                print("You cannot go that way.")

        # Check if the player wants to collect an item
        elif command.startswith('get '):
            item_name = command[4:].strip().capitalize()
            if 'item' in rooms[current_room]:
                room_item = rooms[current_room]['item'].capitalize()
                if item_name.lower() == room_item.lower():
                    items_collected.append(room_item)  # Use room_item instead of item_name
                    print(f"You have obtained the {room_item}.")
                else:
                    print(f"There is no {item_name} in this room.")
            else:
                print("There are no items to collect in this room.")

        # Check win condition
        if allitems(items_collected):
            print("\nCongratulations! You've collected all six mystical artifacts.")
            print("You are now ready to confront the Shadow Sorcerer in the Thorned Thicket!")
            break

        # Check if the player is in the Thorned Thicket
        if current_room == 'Thorned Thicket' and not allitems(items_collected):
            print("You cannot enter the Thorned Thicket without collecting all items first.")
            print("NOM NOM...GAME OVER!")
            print("Thanks for playing the game. Hope you enjoyed it.")
            break

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Can anyone help? I'm trying to see what I am missing as far as the game ending. I collected all the items but once I go the final room it tells me that I don't have all items. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

One error (and I don't know if it's the only one in your game) is a mismatch in case between the collected items and the room items. Note that `str.capitalize()` will only capitalize *the first letter* and turn everything else lower case. You probably mean to use `str.title()` instead which will capitalize the first letter of each word.

This error is even visible to a player of your game:

```
*************************
Enter your move:
get luminous crystal
You have obtained the Luminous crystal.
You are in the Ancient Oak Grove
There is an item in this room: Luminous Crystal   <-- Crystal with capital 'C'
Inventory: ['Luminous crystal']                   <-- Oops, lowercase 'c'
*************************
```

And in the end, `"Luminous Crystal"` will not compare equal to `"Luminous crystal"` because they are not the same strings. Same for all the other items. Because of this, `allitems()` will always return `False`.

You can easily workaround this problem by repeating your mistake and changing the `allitems` function to also use `str.capitalize()`:

```py
def allitems(items_collected):
    i = [ x.capitalize() for x in ['Luminous Crystal', 'Moonflower Petal', "Goblin's Key", 'Ancient Rune Tablet', 'Spider Silk Rope',
         'Thornbane Potion']]
    return set(items_collected) == set(i)  # Check if the sets are equal
```

In fact, it would be better to use case-insensitive string comparison using e.g. `str.casefold()` if - and only if - you mean to compare strings. Just leave them untouched, otherwise. Looks better in the user interface, anyway.

In general, I'd advise to use a debugger or at least `print()` your variables to know their values. But you already do the latter.